# SAS: error 180-322 statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order? What am I doing wrong here?

Tags: sas

Here's my non working code.

```
data _NULL_;
infile datalines;
input name $ class date mmddyy10. type $ quantity;
profit = quantity*1.5;
datalines;
Adriana 21 3/21/2000 MP 7
Nathan  14 3/21/2000 CD 19
Matthew 14 3/21/2000 CD 14
Claire  14 3/22/2000 CD 11
Caitlin 21 3/24/2000 CD 9
Ian     21 3/24/2000 MP 18
Chris   14 3/25/2000 CD 6
Anthony 21 3/25/2000 MP 13
Stephen 14 3/25/2000 CD 10
Erika   21 3/25/2000 MP 17
;
File '/folders/myfolders/sasuser.v94/Library/candysales.txt' Print;
Title;
PUT @5 'Candy sales report for ' name 'from classroom ' class 
  //@5 'Congratulations! You sold ' quantity ' boxes of candy'
   /@5 'and earned' profit dollar8.2 'for field trip.';
PUT _PAGE_;
RUN;
```

I keep getting the error

```
error 180-322 statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order
```

I have tried changing the File statement's placement but I keep getting the same error. I am new to SAS and still learning, but I can't find a solution for this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the datalines and data need to be the end of the step. So suggest you move the file statement and put statements to before the datalines statement. And move the title statement to before the data step. Title statement are global statements.

Comment: That's correct.  The `;` at the end of the `datalines` section ends the Data Step.  The `PUT` and `FILE` statements below it are outside that Data Step.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. So if I understand correctly now, the file writing system is part of dataset step, so the files must be written one row at a time using the program vector, as is the case when creating a normal dataset within SAS. Right?

Comment: Yes.  You have a single DATA step.  All the code for the step goes inside the step.  The DATA step starts with a DATA statement.  Most DATA steps end with a RUN statement.  In the case of DATALINES or CARDS, that statement actually ends the step.  The run statement is then superfluous (but many people leave it in out of habit, and it doesn't hurt).  Yes, the program data vector, and processing records one at a time, is the same as in every DATA step.